# In Java, how to iterate individual elements of an array with a loop and print each of them?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, factors

I am writing a program that will display the factors of a number generated by user input. I am trying to use an array iterated by a loop. The main method will call the method which carries the array and also print its output based on the user input.

```
package arrayCalculateFactors;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArrayFactors {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num = 0;
        int[] factorOutput = CalculateFactors(num); // Call method containing
                                                    // array.
        System.out.println("The factors of your number are " + factorOutput);
    }

    public static int[] CalculateFactors(int num) {
        Scanner numInitial = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter a number.");
        int numInput = numInitial.nextInt();
        int[] Factors;
        Factors = new int[18];
        for (int i = 1; i <= numInput / 2; i++)
            if (numInput % i == 0) {

            }
        return Factors;

    }
} // End class
```

When I run this program it spits out the memory address, not the factors (input of 10 would print 1, 2, 5, 10). How can I modify the loop to iterate every element of the array? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't print the array. Print the numbers in the array.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to loop over each element of the array and print it individually. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Use a for statement to print the array:

```
System.out.println("Your factor outputs are: " + factorOutput[0]);
for (int i = 1; i < factorOutput.length; i++)
    System.out.println(factorOutput[i]);
```

Edit: This is just an example that would print the array assuming it has at least 1 item.*

Answer (score 0):

> When I run this program it spits out the memory address ...

To print something to standard output use `System.out.print(something)` or `System.out.println(something)`.  If `something` is a reference type, the `print` method calls `Object.toString()` on `something`.  For most reference types that is sufficient, but the `toString()` method for an array type prints out the array's internal type name and its identity hash.  (It looks like a memory address ... but technically it isn't.)

So, to print an array, you need to iterate over the elements, and print them one at a time, with a separator between the elements.  Or use a library method (such as `Arrays.toString()`) that does the formatting for you.

> In Java, how to iterate individual elements of an array with a loop and print each of them?

Just as you have described it.  Write the code yourself.  It will help you learn.  (And don't forget the separators between the numbers!!)